# What would be the python equivalent of String.fromCharCode.apply()

Tags: javascript, python

Specifically, what would the equivalent of `String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(e))` be in Python?

I have tried many different things but nothing seems to quite match up with the decoding of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a list of numbers into a string, first convert to a bytestring then decode into a string:

```py
bytes([72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33]).decode("utf8") # "Hello, world!"
```